# Migrate mailserver from mailinabox to iredmail

Tags: migration, iredmail

I have an existing mailinabox version 12 server on Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS. I have several domains running on it with several users having emails. the users don't have access to the server.

I want to migrate the accounts and data to a iredmail server 1.3.1. I would prefer to leave the passwords the same, making the transfer transparent for the user. I have not been able to find a straight forward guide how to migrate. Anyone out there that can help or share some advice?